# Redirección JQuery sin validar la cantidad de datos enviados

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código `JQuery.ajax` que toma los valores de una tabla en **index.php** y los envía al archivo **insertar.php** el cual procesa los datos y los guarda en `MySQL`. Cuando los datos son enviados, redirecciona a **vista.php**. Hasta ahí todo bien.

```
jQuery(document).on('submit','#agregar', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'insertar.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    })
    .done(function(respuesta) {
        console.log(respuesta);
        if (!respuesta.error) {
            alert('Los datos se han guardado con éxito!');
            location.href = 'vista.php';
        } else {
        alert('Algo salió mal!, verifica los datos ingresados');
        }
    })
    .fail(function(resp) {
        console.log(resp.responseText);
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    })
});
```

El número de columnas de la tabla es dinámico (8, 9, 10 u 11 según el caso). Cuando son once columnas, guarda los datos y redirecciona, sin embargo, cuando son menos de once columnas, guarda la información en la base de datos pero no redirecciona.

¿Hay alguna manera de que envíe los datos sin validar la cantidad de columnas y redireccione a **vista.php**?

Comment: valida los warning que te envie puede ser eso!

Comment: Si envío una tabla con 10 columnas, por ejemplo, el error es `Undefined index: columna11 in ../insertar.php`, pero no es un problema ya que el valor de la columna 11 puede quedar vacío en `MySQL`. Quiero que omita ese error y haga la redirección.

Comment: if(isset($post["index"])) or error_reporting(0);

Comment: deberías poner el código de `insertar.php`. Evidentemente el problema esta ahí.

Comment: pon el código de tu php, pero estoy casi seguro que lo resuelves fácil con un `isset($_POST['nombre_de_la_variable'])` ;

Comment: Funciona con `isset($_POST['nombre_de_la_variable']);` Gracias @Sr1871